# Query regarding url_for in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have been working on a Flask project. But I have run into an issue.
To understand my problem properly, you have to take a look at my folder structure.
[image]

[image]

I want to access the '`./static/data/wordlist.txt`' in my `models.py` file using `url_for` syntax.
This is what I have written: `url_for('static', filename='data/wordlist.txt')`.
But flask is giving me an error saying: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/data/wordlist.txt'`
Any help as to what I should do would be great!!

Comment: what is the purpose(what are you going to use it for) of the URL that is being built

Comment: I am making a url shortener. wordlist.txt contains a number of random words from which the program chooses a word randomly and add it to the database. For this purpose, I want to access wordlist.txt inside models.py

Comment: Please make a note that I have already tried to do this using `with open("./static/data/wordlist.txt) as file`. But it is giving me the same error.

Comment: may be you should use absolute path, `dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and use `wordlist_path = os.path.join(dir_name, "static/data/wordlist.txt")`

Comment: My aim is to host this in an online server. So giving absolute path is not an option for me. I have to use url_for.

Comment: I have updated my comment please have a look

Comment: I have another doubt! Will this work when I deploy it to an online server like Heroku?

Comment: yes as long as the directory structure remains intact as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `app.url_root` to get a path relative to your code.

```
wordlist_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/data/wordlist.txt")

with open(wordlist_path) as f:
    ...
```